# How to add customer id in Product url

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using magento 1.9. when clicking add to cart button, want to add customer id (who logged in) at the end of product URL (like [http://www.google.com/product_1&cusomer_id=1](http://http/www.google.com/product_1&cusomer_id=1)) is it possible?

Comment: you can easily get customer id from session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do it?
It is not safe enough to do so,
It will be something like:

```
$this->getAddToCartUrl($product)."&customer_id=".$customerData->getId()
```